# Coming from naive set theory, are the following understanding right in ZF system?

Tags: set-theory

1. In ZF system, a subset $S'$ of set $S$ is: If $S'$ is a set and for any object $b$ $b\in S'\implies x\in S$.
   That is, before being a subset, $S'$ must be a set by itself.
2. The set of integer $\mathbb{N}$ is set in both naive set theory and in ZF system.
   A collection $C$ of an infinite number of arbitrarily selected integer is a subset in 
   naive set theory. But $C$ is not a subset in ZF system.
3. The power set of $\mathbb{N}$ in naive set theory is quite different from that in ZF system.
   The power set of $\mathbb{N}$ in naive set theory has many more elements than that in ZF system.
4. Although the power set of $\mathbb{N}$ in ZF system has less element than that of 
   naive set theory, 
   The Cantor's power set theorem works always: The power set of $\mathbb{N}$ in ZF system 
   has a bigger cardinality than $\mathbb{N}$.

Still unsolved question:

1. In naive set theory, set of real number $\mathbb{R}$ has 1-1 mapping with the power set of $\mathbb{N}$.
   Is there a such mapping in ZF system? That is, is $\mathbb{R}$ a set in ZF system? If yes, how is the mapping defined?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by $2$. Can you give me an example of a set of integers in naive set theory that is not a set in set theory? 3. likewise. What do you mean by "many more?" How do you compare the sizes of infinite sets from different theories?

Comment: There is a fundamental misconstuing of what these systems are. Naive set theory is not about something "real." It exists as it does as an informal way of talking about "sets," but sets are not real, as far as we know. Formal systems of reasoning, like ZF, describe a theory that could cover various "models." Even these models are not "real." ZF exists because naive set theory is either contradictory or too weak to be usable formally.

Comment: So, when you are reasoning in ZF, you are finding common arguments that work in all models of set theory that satisfy the rules of ZF. When you are reasoning in naive set theory, it is entirely unclear what you are reasoning about - it is an informal system. (Unless you are using a formalized version of naive set theory...)

Comment: by 2, I mean a collection of an infinite number of arbitrarily selected integer is a subset in naive set theory, but it's not in ZF system. That is an infinite subset should be built by property or other means. An arbitrary infinite subset in naive set theory is not a subset in ZF system.

Comment: There is nothing in ZF that says that there aren't other sets than the ones you can explicitly define. You can't prove it doesn't exist (and, oddly, you can't really prove it does exist in naive set theory.) Again, describe a set that is not in ZF in naive set theory. "An arbitrary collection" is not a definition of a set.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I mean. It's not a set by definition. It can be a set if it happen to be the same as a set.

Comment: It is a set. Nothing in ZF says that if $S$ is a set, then it can be written is a certain form. It only says that if you can write out a certain form, it describes a set. That doesn't mean that form describes all sets.

Comment: And you still haven't defined a naive set of integers that is not a set in ZF...

Comment: But when I learn a bit more, it seems that ZF system is first order logic. Is that means the property can accept some thing like "for any", "there exists" ? If yes, supposing C is an arbitrary infinite subset in naive set theory, it's not a subset by definition according to the above discussion. If we define a property P(x)="exist b in C so that x=b", then this property will define C as a set in ZF system. Is this understanding of property correct ?

Comment: What is an "arbitrary infinite subset"? You haven't defined what that means. Is $6$ in your subset? Is $99$? You haven't defined a set. Is it the set of all even integers? The set of all primes? There are certainly sets that you can't describe in terms of the form $\{x\in\mathbb N\mid \phi(x)\}$ for some expression $\phi$, but that doesn't mean that the set doesn't exist just because you can't describe it. (You haven't described your "naive set," yet you insist it exists.)

Comment: In ZF system, a collection of integers is not a set before it's proved to be a set, right ? Now, if we randomly select one integer from every 10 to form a collection, how to prove it's a set ?

Comment: No, that is actually not true in ZF. Everything in ZF is a set, and nothing is not a set. There is no notion of "collection" in ZF. There is no way to even talk about whether a naive set is in ZF, because ZF describes *lots of versions of set theory.* It describes versions of set theory where the continuum hypothesis is true, for example, and versions where it is not.

Comment: A correction to what I said for an arbitrary collection of integers C, 'P(x)="exist b in C so that x=b"' is a property in ZF system. P(x) is not a property in ZF system because C is not an element of first order logic so P(x) is not a valid expression in first order logic.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. $\sf ZF$ proves that the real numbers and $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$ have the same cardinality -- or in other words that there is a bijection between the two.

But your question makes some unclear statements. "The power set in $\sf ZF$ has less elements than in naive set theory". Why? What? How? It is true that if $M$ is a countable model of $\sf ZF$ then it only knows about countably many subsets of $\Bbb N$ (or rather, the object that $M$ thinks is $\Bbb N$). But inside $M$ there are only countably many real numbers too (or rather objects that $M$ thinks are real numbers), and moreover, there is a bijection *inside $M$* between those two objects.

If one considers working internally inside a model of $\sf ZF$ then the "naive arguments" translate immediately to be true.

Comment: If we select 1 integer randomly from every 10 integer, this forms a subset in naive set theory. Does the same collection forms a subset in ZF system ?

Comment: The question is what do you mean by "random integer". If the choice is a mathematical process, then when formalized internally to a model of $\sf ZF$ the result is a set of integers. Because this "process" is nothing more than a function, and the function is an element of the universe (or the model of $\sf ZF$) so it can be subjected to the same axioms that govern the rest of the sets. In particular axioms like replacement and bounded comprehension.

Comment: {3,11,24,31,45,59,...} is a subset in naive set theory. How to prove it's a set in ZF system ?

Comment: What does the $...$ mean?

Comment: A serial of integer, that forms a subset in naive set theory.

Comment: Even in naive set theory, this is not a well-defined set.

Comment: If you just want a set which includes $3,11,24,31,45,59$ then you can easily find a set like that.

Comment: This is an infinite serial. In naive set theory, there is no difference between collection and set. Any collection is a set.

Comment: I don't think the is naive set theory, I think this is extremely naive set theory. @AsafKaragila

Comment: @pierredeboussy: You seem to be misunderstanding how mathematics works, how set theory works, how naive set theory works. Perhaps it is worth to take a break, open up a couple of books and try to learn more about set theory and mathematics.

Comment: @pierredeboussy: To add on my previous comment. You haven't told me what the ellipsis mean. If you want "a serial of integers" then taking all the integers larger than $60$ as well the few that you mentioned gives you a well-defined set. You haven't clarified anything in your comment reply. You just seemed to have repeated previous arguments.

Comment: He failed in comments to the question to tell me what set he was talking about, too. He seems to think that, in ZF, the only subsets of the integers are of the form: $\{x\in\mathbb N\mid \phi(x)\}$ for one of the neccessarily countable formulae $\phi$. It's not an unnatural assumption, but I can't seem to dissuade him that the axioms don't say that.

Comment: @Thomas: Well, that's almost true. Because you can allow parameters. But then the subset can be its own parameter, which means that $\varphi(x,p)$ is just a simple formula $x\in p$.

Comment: Technically, those are the only sets you can prove exist, not that exist. @AsafKaragila

Comment: @Thomas: No, those are all the sets that exist. Again, we allow parameters, and these parameters are allowed to be the sets themselves.

Comment: Okay, I can't see how that gets you all sets.

Comment: @Thomas: Given any set which exists, $p$, consider the set $\{x\in\Bbb N\mid x\in p\}$. Of course this proof of existence is somewhat circular, but it's still valid.

Comment: Well, that's silly. Obviously an set that exists exists, but that is not a naive "definition," that is just a circular specification...

Comment: @Thomas: True. But we can still prove that "If $p$ is a subset of $\Bbb N$, then $p=\{x\in\Bbb N\mid x\in p\}$". Not a great proof, but it's there...

Comment: Yes, it just isn't helpful for answering his confusion, which is based on the difference between what can be *defined* as a set and the (possibility that) the model contains a lot more. I realize the idea that there is little difference between the naive notion of a definition and an application of specification. I even said above several times that in ZF, and subset of $\mathbb N$ is a set. That is not clearing things up for him...

Answer (score 0):

2 is the problem. In naive theory you can pick $\{x| \phi(x)\}$ - a collection of elements that satisfy some condition $\phi$ and call it a set. In ZF you cannot. However you can take $\{x \in X | \phi(x)\}$ - a collection of elements of some set $X$, that satisfy condition $\phi$. [There is an axiom for this.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification)